# How can I interpolate between two different animations?

Tags: animation, nla-editor

In the NLA Editor:

[image]

See how there is a slight positional change when going from `Idle` to `StandingAttack`? Is it possible to somehow merge these two animations together so going from `Idle` to `StandingAttack` is one single, fluid motion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The brutal answer is to animate a transition between the two different strips.

First consider how much of the end of the first strip and the beginning of the second strip you want to preserve.  If you want to shave some frames off of one or the other you can do that by adjusting the parameters of the strips (which does not affect the original actions, it just changes how much of that action is incorporated into your animation).

Then create a new strip that bridges the frames between the end of the first strip and the beginning of the second and populate it with keyframes that animate the figure how you want it to move.

One workflow for this process would be

1. create keyframe from position (or whatever) to begin a new primary action at the frame where the transitional animation will begin.
2. Push that new action down into the NLA track using the vv icon.
3. Alter the `End Frame` of the new strip to be the end of the transitional animation.
4. Create a new NLA track ( `Add`>`Add Tracks` )
5. Use `Edit`>`Track Ordering`>`Down` to move that track below the existing track.
6. Use `Edit`>`Move Strips Down` to move the brand new strip into the new lower NLA track.
7. Scrub the time line to the frame from the second (old) strip to pick up the position from that strip
8. With the new strip selected, <kbd>Tab</kbd> to begin editing its action.
9. Insert a new keyframe using the value we got from the second strip
10. select the first strip and change its `Extrapolation` from `Hold` to `Nothing`
11. Alternatively, move the NLA track with the new strip to the top of the tracks and make sure its `Extrapolation` is `Nothing`

I created an animated gif that is too large to put on stackexchange:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2Wy3tK1vORHc1FCZEFPYWtkZzQ

Now since I was just dealing with the location of a single cube this process was relatively easy.  Since you are dealing with an armature's animation and your animation consists of a large number of fcurves for the orientation of many bones, steps 1 and 9 will have to be repeated for every bone that has a keyframe.  Do not repeat steps 2-8.  Use the single new strip to contain all of the keyframes for all the bones of the transitional animation.

Comment: Here are my [frames](https://i.gyazo.com/1b2e6d685b55cd59a50746978fe12b75.png), so edit these inside the Action Editor and then use the NLA Editor to "merge" them if you will? (closely adjacent to each other?)

Comment: Aw man, I forgot how many fcurves there are in an armature.  The workflow is NOT going to be trivial (which is why I used the word "brutal").  I'll see if I can cobble together some screenshots and an extended narrrative.

Comment: WoW @ that edit, this is beyond helpful. Really appreciate it

Comment: If you hit any snags, go ahead and leave a comment and I'll eventually notice and clean up the narrative to help the next guy that follows in your footsteps.